# Why 'IF' made this code 2x faster as the output is the same and 'IF' make an extra check?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I was studying this fast Sieve of Eratosthenes generator and just wondered why, with the 'If check' of every item index, the code run faster than without this check. Who would think that!? Is it a trick to use in general?

```
import time    

def first(n):
    s=time.time()
    full_range = list(range(n))
    zeroes = [0] * n
    '''multiply n until sqrt(n)'''
    for r in range(2, int(n**.5) + 1):
        if full_range[r]:  ##HERE##
            full_range[2 * r:n:r] = zeroes[2 * r:n:r]   
    return list(filter(None, full_range)), print (time.time()-s)


def second(n):
    s=time.time()
    full_range = list(range(n))
    zeroes = [0] * n
    '''multiply n until sqrt(n)'''
    for r in range(2, int(n**.5) + 1):
        #if full_range[r]:   ##HERE##
        full_range[2 * r:n:r] = zeroes[2 * r:n:r]
    return list(filter(None, full_range)), print (time.time()-s)

print(first(100000) == second(100000))

First  0.3749978542327881 seconds
Second 0.9687492847442627 seconds
True
```

Comment: Because its doing a lot in the if, adding the if takes away a whole chunk of work

Comment: also `100000 != 1000000`, `second` is doing more work

Comment: @NickA, What work it takes away? Could you explain?

Comment: @vaultah the difference was my mistake editing the text here, not in the code.

Comment: @FlaxFerrari `full_range[2 * r:n:r] = zeroes[2 * r:n:r]` potentially won't be run in the first example. It will always be run in the second example though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In words, the process you're doing says "zero out the flags for all multiples of this number."  The `if` statement says "do the next step *only if* the current number is a prime."

The second sieve has to zero out all multiples of 2, then 3, then 4, ... for every number in the sieve.  The first one zeroes out only multiples of primes: 2, then 3, then ...

When it reaches 4, it sees that 4 is already zeroed.  Any multiple of 4 is *also* a multiple of 2, so they're already zeroed.  Marking them again is wasted work.

Now we do 5, skip 6, do 7, skip 8, 9, and 10, ...

When we do that work only for prime divisors, we save a lot of work.

Comment: Now I see! When 'IF' checks  r and there is 0 there, 'IF' consider it as false and pass. 
  
The 'IF' speedup is in replace any multiple with 0 (None, False) because Python considered 0 as false condition.
I tested to change 0 with 99 and no speed gain.

´a = [x if x %2 else 99 for x in range(100)]  
for r in range(100):  
    if a[r]:  
    print(a[r])´  
´a = [x if x %2 else 0 for x in range(100)]´

Comment: Right: 0 is what we call "Falsey" (as opposed to "Truthy").  BTW, many mark-ups don't work in comments.

Comment: So my question is answered: this is a trick and can be used in general. Thank you.

Comment: And I remembered that "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex"... if full_range[r] != 0:

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an extreme example as to why the speed up is happening here:

```
def first(n):
    s=time.time()
    a = []
    for r in range(n):
        a += [r]
        if r%2:
            for i in range(r):
                a[i] = i
    return a, print (time.time()-s)

def second(n):
    s=time.time()
    a = []
    for r in range(n):
        a += [r]
        for i in range(r):
            a[i] = i
    return a, print (time.time()-s)

>>> first(10000) == second(10000)
1.7188639640808105
3.406471014022827
True
```

By adding the `if` statement you get rid of a loop which ultimately doesn't affect the outcome of the code.  By not running this loop (in your case an extended slice) your program can spend more time actually on the problem instead of spending time doing something which will have no effect on the final result.

**EDIT**
Interestingly, when running the code that you provided my times were similar enough that it didn't really matter which you used(with sometimes the first being slower than the second):

```
>>> print(first(100000) == second(100000))
0.015606880187988281
0.015592098236083984

>>> print(first(100000) == second(100000))
0.015619993209838867
0.015625953674316406

>>> print(first(100000) == second(100000))
0.0
0.015592098236083984

>>> print(first(100000) == second(100000)) #something wrong with this one
0.0
0.03125309944152832

>>> print(first(100000) == second(100000))
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Here it is consistent 2~3x faster with 'if' than without.
Python 3.6.1 x64 windows
0.031247854232788086
0.06250166893005371
True